# How do I calculate the temperature change in a gaseous reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, temperature, ideal-gas, gas-phase-chemistry

So, with $\pu{3 mol}$ of $\ce{H2}$ and $\pu{3 mol}$ of $\ce{Cl2}$ and given the reaction $\ce{H2(g) + Cl2(g) -> 2 HCl(g)}$ with $\Delta H=\pu{-184.6 kJ/mol}$, I am supposed to calculate the work done on the surroundings of the system at $\pu{1 atm}$ and $\pu{25^\circ C}$.

My current thought process for this is to calculate the enthalpy change of the system first, which is $\Delta H \cdot n_{\ce{H2}}=\pu{-553.8 kJ}=-q_{\mathrm{rxn}}$. Assuming constant pressure, I tried to calculate $\Delta T=\frac{q}{m\cdot c}$, so I could calculate the volume change through the Ideal Gas law and then calculate the work $w=P\cdot \Delta V$. However, things went awry as I realised I didn't know the heat capacity of $\pu{HCl}$ nor did the exercise give it to me.

So, am I going about this the wrong way or am I just supposed to know the heat capacity of $\ce{HCl}$ off the top of my head?

Comment: Useful links for text and formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) // Notice \ce{} and \pu{}

Comment: There are unit names/unit symbols kilogram/kg and mole/mol. So 3 mol like 3 kg, or 3 moles like 3 kilograms, but no 3 mols. (and none of those are written in italic)

Comment: The diatomic molecule $\ce{HCl}$ may be considered as an ideal gas. Its heat capacity at constant pressure is then : $\pu{\frac{7}{2}R}$, with $\pu{R = 8.314 J K^{-1} mol^{-1}}$

Comment: It is more complicated due transition from 7/2R J/K/mol region to 9/2R J/K/mol region because of waking up highly quantized vibration contribution.

Comment: See temperature dependence of HCl molar heat capacity on [Engineering toolbox](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7647010&Mask=1&Type=JANAFG&Table=on#JANAFG) (generally great source of empirical data). the empirical formula to compute value is included.

Comment: See also [wikipedia - Molar heat capacity - Frozen and_active degrees of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_heat_capacity#Frozen_and_active_degrees_of_freedom)

Comment: You start with 6 moles of ideal gas at 25 C and 1 atm, and, in the end you have 6 moles of ideal gas at 25 C and 1 atm.  So what was the volume change?

Comment: @ChetMiller Hmm, nice, I have somehow missed the final conditions, what is quite funny, considering I have been editing it.

Comment: @ChetMiller The reaction is exothermic. The released heat should increase temperature and expand the gas, shouldn't it?

Comment: Not if you remove heat to make the final temperature 25 C